# Where are my Screenshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> to take a few Minecraft screenshots. Later I couldn't find them. Where are they stored on my computer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Windows, your screenshots are stored in the `%appdata%\.minecraft\screenshots` folder. On Linux, they are stored in `~/.minecraft/screenshots`.

To get to this folder on Windows XP/Vista/7 open the start menu, select "Run" and enter `%appdata%`. Navigate to `.minecraft > screenshots` to get to your screenshots.

To get to this folder on Windows 7/8/10 open the start menu and enter `%appdata%` in the search bar. Click on `Roaming`, navigate to `.minecraft > screenshots`, and there are your pictures.

To get to this folder on Ubuntu, open the file explorer (nautilus), press ^L (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) and type in `~/.minecraft/screenshots`, then press <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.

Comment: `%appdata%` is/used to be by default equal to `C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Roaming`.

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked in `%appdata%\.minecraft\screenshots` folder?

Taken from here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Screenshots

Answer (score 6):

Since Minecraft 1.7.2, you can **click the screenshot name in the chat to reveal the file's location**.

> "Saved screenshot as" messages can now be clicked to open the screenshot, takes you to the .minecraft folder

<sup>Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history</sup>