# I saved some screenshots in minecraft on my Mac, how to share?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saved several minecraft screenshots on my Mac. Now I need to find them and either email them to my friends or save them to a thumb drive. How can I do this?

Comment: This question isn't realy a duplicate of [where are my screenshots](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125490/where-are-my-screenshots) since this one is about mac path

Comment: When you take a screenshot, _it tells you where it stored it._

Answer (score 3):

By default screenshot folder on mac for Minecraft is here:

```
/Users/<yourUsername>/Library/Application Support/minecraft/screenshots/
```