# Finding My Minecraft/screenshot folder: Using iMac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need help re-downloading/finding my Minecraft folder, as I want to find my screenshots folder within that folder. I think I may have deleted the Minecraft folder or I otherwise can't find it. I've looked at nearly everywhere on the internet saying the answers

"Look in your .minecraft folder" or "Press go and copy and paste this: '/Library/Application Support/minecraft'"

However, these solutions haven't worked and I can't find my folder. Where can I find this folder? I'm using a **Mac**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is my screenshots folder?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250688/where-is-my-screenshots-folder)

Comment: @king14nyr Actually, I'd say it's more than just a duplicate since it's made by the same user.

Comment: @king14nyr, quite right, but the other answer is of lower quality, and does not have any suggested answers. Might I suggest flagging the other question as a duplicate of this one? Also, we should not be having a PC/Mac exclusive question imo; we should ask how to find the screenshots folder, and provide space for a PC answer, and a Mac answer, as opposed to having a mac question and a PC question.

Comment: Related: [Where are my Screenshots?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/125490/4797)

Comment: @Timelord64 I flagged this question as soon as it was made as a duplicate of the older one, since it was a clear duplicate created by the same user. There were comments and some discussion in the older one, so I flagged this one as a duplicate of the other. Now that this question has answers and more content, it makes sense that the older is marked a duplicate (which I see has been done).

Answer (score 1):

Open your MC-Launcher and click on "Edit Profile".

[image]

Then click on "Open Game Dir".

[image]

Didn't test on Mac(because I have none), but these buttons should work on any system.

Comment: I agree that this *should* work, but if someone with a mac could confirm it (and *maybe* replace the screenshots), that'd be great.

Answer (score -2):

When you take a screenshot, it's path is shown in the chat.

Comment: It doesnt really show the path, but you can click on the filename to open the screenshot file with the standard programm for that filetype.

Answer (score -4):

Press <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
An execute window will appear, in there type `%appdata%`

Go to the `.minecraft` folder and then the screenshots folder.
There you will find all your screenshots.

Comment: "imac" is not a windows device, so this is not an answer.